# How to check if contact has edited image on windowphone

Tags: image, windows-phone-8, contacts, avatar

I'm synchronizing contact from phone with local databse in my app. I want to updated edited contact but on windowphone i don't find something like "dated modify". I can only compare name, phone number,.. but i don't know detect edited image of contact.

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can compare two images by converting them to byte[ ] or pixel[ ] and then comparing

```
bool equal = byte1.SequenceEqual(byte2);  // using System.Linq
```

I know this is a crude method and consumes a lot of time. Also, why would you like to maintain a local database of contacts when you can get the system's contact list any time you wish.

Comment: Thanks.
I think maintain all contact in local database will take a lot of performance. So I only want change the contact which has edited in system's contact list.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this would be to grab the image, take a hash of it and then store that hash.
Then when doing a compare grab and hash the image again and compare the hashes.

Just storing a hash will take a lot less space than a copy of the whole image.

Comment: Thanks for your idea.
I'm storing the hash of image in my database by using:
 Contact.GetPicture().GetHashCode()
But when i get hash the image again in the second times to compare. The hash has changed although i don't edit anything in Contact People.
I don't know whether the hash of image is a UID.

Please, support me.